# java get only children 's values of a treeItem

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

To display a treeItem Children I made:

```
  System.out.println(
treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getChildren());
```

OUTPUT:

```
[TreeItem [ value: host1 ], TreeItem [ value: port1 ], TreeItem [ value: user1 ], TreeItem [ value: bd1 ]]
```

However, I only want to have a result with the values `('host1', 'port1'..)`.

So how can I manipulte that output?

Comment: Did you tried to use `.getValue()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getChildren()` returns an `ObservableList<TreeItem<T>>` object. This is actually a list. If you want to print only the values, you should iterate over this list and print the value of each `TreeItem` object using the `getValue()` method.

```
List<TreeItem<Object>> children = 
treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getChildren();

for (TreeItem<Object> child : children) {
    System.out.println(child.getValue())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With java8 streams you can do it quite easily:

```
List<TreeItem> children = treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getChildren();
List<String> childrenValues = children.stream() // get stream from list
    .map(TreeItem::getValue) // equal to: item -> item.getValue()
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect all to a single list
System.out.println(values);
```

Which should print the desired result